# Selecting among possible attribute values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to select item with jQuery like this:

```
// pseudocode
$('input[name=val1 or val2 or val3...]')
```

Now I'm trying to do the next:

```
$("input[name='A'] input[name='B'] input[name='C']").blur(function() {
    var result = parseFloat($("input[name='A']").val()) +
        parseFloat($("input[name='B']").val()) -
        parseFloat($("input[name='C']").val());

    alert(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

but that's not working. It is working only with one item `$("input[name='A'])` in selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("input[name='A'],input[name='B'],input[name='C']")
```

insted of

```
$("input[name='A'] input[name='B'] input[name='C']")
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to accomplish that, here's one example:

`$('input[name="A"], input[name="B"], input[name="C"]')`

For all of them, check out [multiple attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware you'd have to explicitly specify the options:

```
$('input[name="val1"], input[name="val2"], input[name="val3"]')
```

You could, if the names had the same format (and began with the `val` string):

```
$('input[name^="val"]');
```

Or, but this is more less equal to the first approach, though it looks less efficient (and may be):

```
$('input[name]').filter(
    function(){
        return (this.name.indexOf('val') > -1);
    });
```

Somewhat surprisingly, on Chrome 18/Win XP, the second option (`$('input[name^="val"]');`) is fastest (though perhaps it's able to more easily rely upon `document.querySelectorAll()` for its implementation. The final approach, with `.filter()`, is, as expected, the slowest.

[JS Perf test-case](http://jsperf.com/testing-input-selection-by-name-value).

Incidentally, while I originally missed the syntax error, the lack of commas to delimit the selectors meant that your original, not-working, code was looking for child elements of an `input`, which would be invalid mark-up.

Use the commas to identify separate element-selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just give them all the same class and then select them like this

`$('.selectedInputs')`

Comment: I was going for the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the reference (especially comments below) http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ alternative solution can be considered:

```
$('input[name=A][name=B]')
```

cool!